# The value of $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^p}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Prove the value of the series
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^p}$$
>   is between $\frac12$ and $1$.

It's easy to prove the result of $<1$, but I can only get the result of $>\frac12$ when $p>1$.

In fact you can get the whole result easily by observing
$$\eta(s)=\frac1{\Gamma(s)}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x+1}dx$$
but it's too "advanced". There must be proper methods!

Comment: Just check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function.

Comment: @user1952009 I just suggested to check the properties of this function as an avenue to the answer but you did better.

Comment: $\displaystyle\eta(s)=\frac{\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x+1}dx}{\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^{s-1}e^{-x}dx}$ says that $\eta(s) < 1$ since $\frac{1}{e^x+1}< e^{-x}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $p > 0$ $$\eta(p)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(2n-1)^{-p} -( 2n)^{-p}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{2n-1}^{2n} p x^{-p-1}dx$$

Note that for $n \ge 2$ $$\frac12\int_{2n-1}^{2n+1} p x^{-p-1}dx<\int_{2n-1}^{2n} p x^{-p-1}dx<\frac12\int_{2n-3}^{2n-1} p x^{-p-1}dx$$ 
Summing over $n$ 
$$\frac{1}{2}= \frac12\int_1^\infty p x^{-p-1}dx<\eta(p)< \frac{p}2(1+\int_1^\infty  x^{-p-1}dx) = \frac12+ \frac{p}{2}$$
So we proved that $\lim_{p \to 0} \eta(p) = \frac12$ and $\eta(p)\in (1/2,1)$ for $p \in (0,1)$.

Conclude with what you said, that for $p \ge 1$, $\eta(p) \in (1/2,1)$.